# How to read unicode "\u1f40d" in java or android?

Tags: java, android, unicode, encoding

I'm recently trying to dig something.

Can I read "\u1f40d" in java or android?

I tried like this

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream("\u1f40d".getBytes()), "utf-8"));
utf8 = rd.readLine();
```

But the result is

```
ὀd
```

I expect a result is  (This is a snake emoticon. http://chars.suikawiki.org/string?s=%F0%9F%90%8D)

You can see this special character in IE or Mac Chrome, Safari(Can not view in my Window Chrome)

Please help me

Comment: When Java sees `\u`, it expects it to be followed by exactly 4 hex digits.  You've given it 5.  So the result is whatever character is Unicode U+1F40, followed by the character `'d'`.  You'll need another mechanism to create a character U+10000 and higher, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I get the same results in JavaScript: `'\u1f40d'` gives me “ὀd” but `''.codePointAt(0).toString(16)` gives me “1f40d”.

Comment: There’s got to be some function in Java similar to `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt('1f40d',16))`… because that works in JS…

Comment: @Xufox I selected an answer. Thank you! Please refer Mark's.

Comment: `1f40d` is UTF-32… Using a surrogate pair of `\uD83D\uDC0D` should yield the snake as well but in UTF-16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
int codePoint = Integer.parseInt("1f40d", 16 ); // it will be 128013
System.out.println(new String(new int[]{codePoint}, 0, 1));
```

Comment: `int codePoint = 0x1f40d;` is a lot simpler--no need to go through `parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the the `\uXXXX` notation is for a 16 bit `char`, with 4 hex digits. Unicode code points above 2<sup>16</sup>

```
int codePoint = 0x1f40d;
System.out.println(new String(new int[] {codePoint}, 0, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i have this string -

```
String myString = "\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World";
```

and i want to convert it, then you can do this programatically by -

```
String str = myString.split(" ")[0];
str = str.replace("\\","");
String[] arr = str.split("u");
String text = "";
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
    text += (char)hexVal;
}
// Text will now have Hello
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry @Ashish Tamrakar. Your method is not working for me. The result of your method is "ὀd". But cheers you too!